# Set up a linux shell script cron job on Plesk 9.5.4

Tags: linux, cron, shell-scripting

Operating system    Linux 2.6.18-028stab089.1
Parallels Plesk Panel version   9.5.4

Set up a test cron job in Settings>Scheduled Tasks>user "root">
`*  *   *   *   *   /var/www/cron/webcrontest.sh >/dev/null 2>&1`
The script contains this:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "test" >>/var/www/cron/webcrontest.log
```

However, nothing gets output in that file.
How could I find out what's the problem? I have no access to the e-mail that the cron jobs could be sent to (not my host, trying to set up a cron job for a client because he doesn't listen when I say it's the sysadmins job).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are discarding any diagnostic information you might have by sending `stdout` & `stderr` to `/dev/null` (`>/dev/null 2>&1`).

Try redirecting the output to a file and seeing what it contains

```
* * * * * /var/www/cron/webcrontest.sh &>/tmp/webcrontest.out
```

Which will write stdout and stderr to `/tmp/webcrontest.out.`

Edit: From the comments, you have DOS line endings, use dos2unix to remove the ^M line endings

```
dos2unix /var/www/cron/webcrontest.sh
```

Comment: Ok, I got this: `/bin/sh: /var/www/cron/webcrontest.sh: /bin/sh^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory` What can I do about it? Edit: changed to /bin/bash, will see if it helps any. Edit2: /bin/bash - same thing.

Comment: Use a linux editor to edit the file. You'll probably see ^M at the end of each line, remove them. Is this a file that you edited on windows and uploaded ?

Comment: Just edited it with Notepad++, changed EOL and it works now. I'll test it with some more stuff.

Comment: Yeah, that works too. lots of solutions when you know what the problem is ;)

Answer (score -1):

```
dos2unix /var/www/cron/webcrontest.sh
```

Comment: EOL>Unix format, UTF-8 without BOM... what do I need to convert there?